# Blazor WASM - convert ChangeEventArgs to enum type

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-5.0

I am writing an ASP.NET Blazor WASM program with an HTML select dropdown. It has a `value` attribute that is linked to an enum variable type, and calls a custom method with the `@onchange` directive.

**Dropdown component**

```
<select name="category" class="form-control selectpicker " value="@_searchCategory" @onchange="UpdateCategory">
    @foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SearchCategory)))
        {
            <option value="@item">@item</option>
        }
</select>
```

**Search Variables**

```
private SearchCategory _searchCategory = SearchCategory.Port;
private enum SearchCategory
    {
        Port,
        Name,
        Script,
        Version
    }
```

**UpdateCategory method**

```
UpdateCategory(ChangeEventArgs args) {
    _searchCategory = args.Value; //error
    PerformSearch();
...
}
```

How can I cast `string` (*args.Value*) to `Enum` (*SearchCategory*)?

Comment: What was your problem again? You are trying to cast a string (args.Value) to an Enum...so...

Comment: @Ergis yeah that's the problem I am having now. I already tried casting with (SearchCategory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `args` to `string` and then convert the `string` to `SearchCategory` as shown below.

```
private void UpdateCategory(ChangeEventArgs args) {
        var searchCategoryAsString = args.Value?.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCategoryAsString)) return;

        _searchCategory = (SearchCategory) Enum.Parse(typeof(SearchCategory), searchCategoryAsString);
        Console.WriteLine(_searchCategory);
    }
```